# cassandra-env.sh file is not able to read JMX prometheus parameter

Tags: java, cassandra, prometheus

Added the Given. line in Cassandra.sh file:-

**JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -javaagent:/etc/cassandra/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar=7070:/etc/cassandra/jmx_exporter.yml"**

Not able to access the curl http://10.x.x.13:7070

As per apport.logs >

ERROR: apport (pid 19530) Mon Aug  2 14:51:36 2021: called for pid 19507, signal 6, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 19530) Mon Aug  2 14:51:36 2021: executable: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java (command line "java -Xloggc:/var/log/cassandra/gc.log -**javaagent:/etc/cassandra/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar=7070:/etc/cassandra/jmx_exporter.yml** -javaagent:/etc/cassandra/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar=7070:/etc/cassandra/jmx_exporter.yml -ea -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k -XX:StringTableSize=1000003 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms4G -Xmx4G -Xmn900M -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=600 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M -XX:CompileCommandFile=/etc/cassandra/hotspot_compiler -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password -Djava.library.path=/usr/share/cassandra/lib/sigar-bin -Dcassandra.metricsReporterConfigFile= -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra -Dcassandra.storagedir=/var/lib/cassandra -Dcassandra-pidfile=/var/run/cassandra/cassandra.pid -cp /etc/cassandra:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/airline-0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/asm-5.0.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/caffeine-2.2.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:/usr/share/cassandra

**Also Nothings is coming when I run > ps aux | grep cass**

output:-

```
cassand+  1308  0.3  2.1 4619804 351380 ?      Sl   Aug02   3:38 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Dagent-pidfile=/var/run/datastax-agent/datastax-agent.pid -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/datastax-agent/log4j.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/datastax-agent/kerberos.config -jar datastax-agent-6.7.7-standalone.jar /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml
cassand+  7835 34.4 55.4 56100300 9109792 ?    SLl  Aug02 362:16 java -Xloggc:/var/log/cassandra/gc.log -ea -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k -XX:StringTableSize=1000003 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms4G -Xmx4G -Xmn900M -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=600 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M -XX:CompileCommandFile=/etc/cassandra/hotspot_compiler -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Comment: *Also Nothings is coming when I run > ps aux | grep cass* I'm confused. Your `ps` output shows the opposite of what you claim…

Comment: I mean when I run ps aux , this entry < javaagent:/etc/cassandra/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar=7070:/etc/cassandra/jmx_exporter.yml  >should be there but its missing...

Comment: Oh I see. Actually I don't know if there's a limit on the output of ps - there might be. The output from the log shows it IS being set

Comment: problem is not with ps, Cassandra-env.sh file is not able to read the Prometheus parameter, don't know why.

Comment: Just to clarify - the real problem is that you can't access the agent via the web interface?

Comment: @g00se  yes, that's right

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output you posted, it looks like you've added the Prometheus JAR twice.

I've noted that you've also got the OpsCenter agent running. You should only use OpsCenter agent OR the Prometheus agent -- not both at the same time since they're collecting the same metrics for the most part.

As a side note in case you weren't aware, DataStax has Metrics Collector for Apache Cassandra (aka MCAC) that collects both operating system (memory, disk, CPU, etc) and Cassandra metrics built on `collectd` + Prometheus + Grafana.

Installation only takes 3 steps:

1. Download the agent
2. Add the agent JAR to the JVM options.
3. Restart Cassandra.

It also comes with pre-configured Prometheus + Grafana dashboards so you can get them up and running in a few minutes. It is open-source so it's free to use -- https://github.com/datastax/metric-collector-for-apache-cassandra. Cheers!

P.S. I see that you're using G1 GC with only a small amount of memory allocated:

```
-Xms4G -Xmx4G -Xmn900M -XX:+UseG1GC
```

G1 GC is designed for larger heap sizes and in my experience it doesn't perform well for smaller heaps. You should also not pin the NewGen size (`-Xmn900M`) to a specific value because G1 GC needs to be able to dynamically resize NewGen depending on workloads, access patterns, etc.

You should switch back to CMS (default in C*) if your nodes don't have a lot of memory. I recommend a minimum of 8GB heap in production with 16GB preferable up to 24GB with CMS. Use G1 GC for heaps between 20 to 31GB maximum (note that a 32GB heap has less addressable objects than 31GB).

Comment: Good advice to follow on GC.  A cluster w/ nodes @ a 4GB heap should definitely be on CMS.  And TBH, with CMS you'll probably want to _double_ the NewGen size from what it currently is.

Comment: Thanks , I will check the advice and let you know.

Comment: @ErickRamirez,  JAR given by MCAC is not giving me cassendra related any metrics like:- mcac_client_request_latency_total , mcac_client_request_latency_bucket etc

Comment: I am using this JAR:- https://github.com/datastax/metric-collector-for-apache-cassandra/releases/download/v0.2.0/datastax-mcac-agent-0.2.0.tar.gz

Comment: BUT FYI:- I am able to collect the Cassandra system-related metrics like ex:- collectd_cpu_total